# NSURLSession does not follow redirection

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

For a screen scraping project I'm using NSURLSession in Swift to read an HTML page. But already the start fails because the returned page gives a redirection to a new webpage and my code doesn't follow that. I thought redirection would work by default, if no delegate is set for the session. But neither case does the redirection. Here's my test project:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse,
    newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(request);
  }

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    var url = NSURL(string: "https://banking.dkb.de");

    let defaultConfigObject = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration();
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil);

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

      let text = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
      // text contains here: <head><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/dkb/"></head>
      if var document = NSXMLDocument(data: data, options: Int(NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML), error: nil) {
        if let forms = document.nodesForXPath("//form[@name='login']", error: nil) where forms.count > 0 {
          let form = forms[0] as! NSXMLNode;

        }
      }
    });

    task.resume();

  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
  }


}
```

What do I have to do to make redirection work here?

**Update:**

On further investigation I found out that it must have to do with the result from the server. For instance using `https://www.google.com` indeed triggers the redirection delegate. However, since any browser can handle also redirection from the bank address, there must be a different approach in place to properly handle that and I'd like to learn how.

Comment: i hope, it helps - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009506-SW1

Comment: Have read this already. Redirecting via meta tags is simply not handled in this way.

Answer (score 2):

NSURLSession supports 302 redirect and https://www.google.com uses it.

On the other hand, https://banking.dkb.de/ uses meta tag as described. It returns 200(OK) as status code so you must handle it reading meta tag.